# Align items inside a list in bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to left align the item name and its description whereas right align the action dropdown.
Also, the spacing between list item and secondary text has to be reduced,

The incorrect output I see now is
[image]

The expected output should be something like this
[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
A First item<br/>
<small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `float-end` class to `<div class="btn-group">` so it becomes `<div class="btn-group float-end">`.

Also, move the `<div>` so it is the first item inside the `<li>`.

To reduce the space between the item and its description, change the `line-height` property of `<li class="list-group-item">`, e.g.
`<li class="list-group-item" style="line-height: 1.1rem">`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="btn-group float-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
A First item<br/>
<small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you also help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298177/make-image-and-text-middle-align-inside-the-list

Answer (score 0):

try this

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>
        A First item<br/>
        <small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
        </div>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```