# Make image and text middle align inside the list

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list where it has title and secondary description besides an image icon. I want to middle align the text and image icon as

[image]

as

[image]

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="btn-group float-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
<img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png"/>            
A First item<br/>
<small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `<img>` to the first child of the `<li>` and add a class of `float-start` to it:

`<img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />            

            <div class="btn-group float-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
A First item<br/>
<small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the gap between image and the title desc has to be reduced. I applied the class https://prnt.sc/LucDs1yV-2t0 but it didnt. Could you help me know where it has to be added?

Comment: @CodeGuy If you want to *reduce* the padding, why are you trying to *add* more with `pe-5`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74311651/add-gap-in-bootstrap-between-image-and-text here is the post.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
        <style>
        .header-intro-section {
            /* display: flex; if you want to show full width, please use it */
            display: inline-flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="btn-group float-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="header-intro-section">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png"/>            
            A First item<br/>
            <small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
            </div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
    <p>
      Start editing to see some magic happen :)
    </p>
    
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <div class="btn-group float-end">
                    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                        <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                
    <img style="float:left;" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png"/> 
    /*DIV for title and description*/           
    <div style="float:left;" >
    A First item<br/>
    <small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
    </div>
                <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
        </ul>
        
    </body>
    
    </html>

The main part of solution is putting title and secondary description into div and assigning this image and div as `"float:left"`
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but the gap between image and the title desc has to be reduced. I applied the class prnt.sc/LucDs1yV-2t0 but it didnt. Could you help me know where it has to be added?

Comment: Can you please check with my solution again ? It has already very less space between  image and the title desc. If you need to decrease more than I'll tell you

Comment: I want to do it by adding a bootstrap class and not inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using bootstrap 5 cdn so try out this with flex, you have use float that is not an issue but you also need to clear the float while using it ([What does the CSS rule "clear: both" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/what-does-the-css-rule-clear-both-do)) so better to use flex. Here is my solution for your problem using flex.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center gap-3">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" alt="img" />
                    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                        <div>A First item</div>
                        <div><small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        Action
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle"
                                role="button">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Edit Modal -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel"
        tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2"
                        data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```