# Add gap in bootstrap between image and text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I need to increase the space between title/desc and the icon image
I have tried adding ms-5 to div tag but that didnt work.

**NOTE: Please dont answer as margin-right:5px, I am looking this to be done using bootstrap css.**

How do I add the gap between

[image]

Here is my code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />            

            <div class="btn-group float-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
                    <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
<div class="ms-5">A First item<br/>
<small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
<div>
            <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
    </ul>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bootstrap provide classes for padding / margin https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: You can use regular CSS for this, `margin-right: 10px`.

Comment: Other than inline styles, how do I make it using bootstrap?

Comment: @Gonzalo Odiard So I meant to post here that ms-5 bootstrap class didnt work. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add bootstrap built in utility class for property, side, size.

`<div class="ms-5 ps-3">A First item<br/>` -> `px-3` will give you padding both left and right of a calculated amount. `ps-3` will give you padding at the start. See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/) for more info.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/networking-manager.png" class="float-start" />

      <div class="btn-group float-end">
        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-display="static" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg-end">
          <li><a data-bs-toggle="modal" href="#exampleModalToggle" role="button" class="dropdown-item" href="#">Edit</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Run</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="ms-5 ps-3">A First item<br/>
        <small class="text-secondary">This is a first item description</small>
        <div>
          <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalToggle" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="exampleModalToggleLabel" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalToggleLabel">Create a file</h1>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"> What is Lorem Ipsum? </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-target="#exampleModalToggle2" data-bs-toggle="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">A second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">A third item</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```